# How to deal with redux clearing the state on refresh/reload

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using redux to maintain a state for my application,
 I am loading the data for redux state from one component through API call and accessing this data on another component, On refresh redux clears the state so state data that was being accessed by another component becomes null/undefined . How to deal with this condition without storing the data in the local storage / cookies as the data is sensitive in nature .

Comment: You can utilize `redux persist` to persist certain reducers in your store.

Comment: yes but it also stores the data in  local storage or some other storage.

Comment: It saves it in `localStorage`. If you are working with secure data, you should not be saving it to `redux` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to store the data neither in local storage and cookies, there is not another place to store it.
If the data is sensitive and you really need to store it, you could hash it before storing, maybe use some usual hash or create your own hash.